# Why is OpenCV's polarWarp introducing artifacts into some images?

Tags: c++, opencv, polar-coordinates, remap

I have some small (typically about 60x60 orless) BGR images for which I'm generating polar projections using OpenCV's warpPolar.  Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally I get an image (from that same camera source as the images that worked OK) that has a scattering of artifacts within it.  Three different interpolation methods all produce artifacts.  I did find that increasing the polar radius eliminates the artifacts, but could someone explain why that would make a difference?

Here is code representative of the call to warpPolar:

```
Mat m = imread( "image.png", IMREAD_COLOR);
Moments mom = moments( m);
int len = //... semi-major axis*2 for ellipse fit
warpPolar( m, polar, Size(), Point( mom.m10/mom.m00, mom.m01/mom.m00) , len, INTER_LINEAR);
```

Here is an image that works OK:

[image: Source blob #1]
--[warpPolar]-->
[image: Blob #1 Polar Projection]

Here is an image that resulted in a rainbow of artifacts about a quarter of the way down and a band of grayish at the bottom, using NEAREST, LINEAR, and LANCZOS4 respectively:

[image: Source blob #2]
--[warpPolar]->
[image]
[image]
[image]

...and then with longer radius...

[image]

Comment: Are you displaying or writing the warped image? Can you include the code you are using to display it? Can you post the original image?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is that the warpPolar( ) call needs an additional flag specifying how to fill in pixels outside of the source image.  This fixed it:

```
warpPolar( m, polar, Size(), Point( mom.m10/mom.m00, mom.m01/mom.m00) , len, INTER_LINEAR | CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS);
```